# how to use navigation drawer in all activities of my project

Tags: android

I have created a navigation drawer and now i want to use it in all my activity can anyone tell me how it is done ? i have gone through various ansers but it didn't help I have created a navigation drawer and now i want to use it in all my activity can anyone tell me how it is done ? i have gone through various ansers but it didn't help

here is my code:

```
public class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private LinearLayout mDrawerList;
    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    protected Toolbar toolbar;
    protected FrameLayout framelayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        framelayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle().toString();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }


        };



        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    }

    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {

        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_Aboutus).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;


    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 1:
                Intent a = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent b = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(b);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int items = item.getItemId();
        switch(items){

            case R.id.action_Settings:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Contact_us:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Contact.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Aboutus:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Profile:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"

        android:background="#0F6177">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"></include>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I think, one navigation drawer can be used only by on Activity. you can add multiple Fragments on your activity. in this way your navigation drawer will be shown with all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all you have to create a base abstract `Activity` with `DrawerLayout`:

```
public abstract class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method overrides the setContentView method to set DrawerLayout as a main layout.
     *
     * @param layoutResID Layout, which will be set in DrawerLayout as a content frame
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

        final ViewStub content = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        content.setLayoutResource(layoutResID);
        content.inflate();

        initDrawer();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes DrawerLayout and DrawerToggle
     */
    private void initDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                null,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(final View view) {
                //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(final View drawerView) {
                //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when user presses the back button. If the drawer is opened, it will be closed.
     * Otherwise will be called the parent implementation.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses a layout `navigation_drawer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@color/gray_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is drawer"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

After that you can simply create some `Activity` and set its layout into `ViewStub` with id "`content_frame`". It will be done automatically in `setContentView` method in `NavigationActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

You also have to use a theme with `ActionBar`:

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And set it in your `manifest` file:

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

...

Comment: how to set the layout into viewstub with id contentframe

Comment: It will be done automatically in setContentView method in NavigationActivity. So just call setContentView(..) as usually

Comment: cant i do this in this same class ?

Comment: i am including an xml in the AbstractActivity class where i have navigation drawer so will that work ?

Comment: ? i am going to write on click methods for that xml in this abstractactivity class where i have my navigation drawer

Comment: Add setContentView() method (as i described in my NavigationActivity) to your AbstractActivity and call from all your Activities setContentView

Comment: its not working it gives me error : No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Comment: did you rename the layout name? do you set R.layout.activity_abstract or R.layout.navigation_drawer?

Comment: i renamed it have a look

Comment: I updated my answer. I have tested it just now, it works. What i have changed: added some TextView in Drawer (android:id="@+id/drawer_container"); added a theme and defined the style for ActionBar

Comment: did you get it? if you still have any questions, let us continue in chat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106139/discussion-between-bipin-and-yital9).

Answer (score 0):

I implimented this code but it isnt working

```
package com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Abstract;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewStub;

import com.astro.famouspandit.R;

public abstract class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method overrides the setContentView method to set DrawerLayout as a main layout.
     *
     * @param layoutResID Layout, which will be set in DrawerLayout as a content frame
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        final ViewStub content =(ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        content.setLayoutResource(layoutResID);
        content.inflate();

        initDrawer();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes DrawerLayout and DrawerToggle
     */
    private void initDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.ic_drawer_button, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                null,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(final View view) {
                //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(final View drawerView) {
                //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when user presses the back button. If the drawer is opened, it will be closed.
     * Otherwise will be called the parent implementation.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start">


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in this class i am extending it:

```
public class Contact extends NavigationActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText mName,mNumber,mEmail,mMessage;
    private FancyButton mSbmt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
```